# Wall collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am trying to get collision to work but when the two rectangles collide they go a little bit into each other but I want the second rectangle to act like a wall. Does someone have any idea how I could fix this? Or is there maybe a better way to add collision to my game? This is what I have right now.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Squarey")
done = False
is_red = True
x = 30
y = 30
x2 = 100
y2 = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

charImg = pygame.image.load('character.png')



rect1 = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60)

rect2 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 60, 60)

x_change = 0
y_change = 0

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


#movement
      #left
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        x_change = -5
        y_change = 0

        #right
      elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_change = 5
        y_change = 0
      #key release left and right
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        x_change = 0
        y_change = 0


      #up    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        y_change = -5
        x_change = 0


        #down
      elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        y_change = 5
        x_change = 0


      #key release up and down
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
      if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        y_change = 0
        x_change = 0 
    rect1.x = rect1.x + x_change
    rect1.y = rect1.y + y_change

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect2)

    if rect1.bottom > screen.get_rect().bottom:
      rect1.center = screen.get_rect().center

    #if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
    if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
      #print("Collision !!")

      rect1.x = rect1.x - x_change
      rect1.y = rect1.y - y_change

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Most likely you are rendering each frame before calculating the collision detection. You need to reverse these two steps.

Comment: make all calculations before `screen.fill((0, 0, 0))`

Comment: BTW: to make collision with two walls - ie. on left and on bottom - better first change only rect.x, next check collisions, next change only rect.y and check collisions again. Do it because `colliderect` doesn't inform if you collide only on left or only on bottom or on both. See examples in [Lab 16: Pygame Platformer Examples](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?&chapter=example_code_platformera)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. It is working right now.

Answer (score 1):

you are drawing the rectangles before setting them back when they hit each other so they move into each other for a moment. Make sure to do all drawing after calculations have been made.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with your program is that you are drawing rect before checking for collision.

Since, there aren't many answers I am writing one for others. You would require two variables `x` and `y` to store the previous position i.e. position before the collision. Then you would need to check if the two rectangles have collided using `Rect.colliderect`. If they have collided reset the current position to the previous position, then draw the wall.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0)

rect1 = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60)
rect2 = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 60, 60)

previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
x_change, y_change = 0, 0

speed = 5

while not done:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -speed
                y_change = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = speed
                y_change = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -speed
                x_change = 0

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = speed
                x_change = 0

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            x_change = 0
            y_change = 0

    previous_x = rect1.x
    previous_y = rect1.y

    rect1.x = rect1.x + x_change
    rect1.y = rect1.y + y_change

    if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
        print("Collision")
        rect1.x = previous_x
        rect1.y = previous_y

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect2)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

If you have many walls store all of their rect in a list. Then use pygame's `Rect.collidelist` to check if there is any collision.(note: collidelist returns -1 if there is no collision). If there are any then reset to the previous position.